# Activation of an open application window

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to activate a window, that I know is open and available, from a list of windows generated using the following code...

```
import ctypes
import win32gui

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, 
ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

titles = []

def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
        titles.append(buff.value)
    return True

EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

size = len(titles)                      # get the size of the list

for a in range (0,size,1):              # print entities that aren't blank
   if titles[a] == "My To Do List.xlsm - Excel":
      print ("Found it")
      win32gui.ShowWindow(titles[a], 5)    # this line is killing me
```

Once the window has been found in the list, I want to grab that window and activate it (make it such that it appears in the front and is able to take commands such as key strokes).  I've tried to use the **win32gui.ShowWindow(titles[a],5)** but I keep getting the error about "*The object is not a PyHANDLE object*".

Is there something I can use in my context to activate the found window or do I need to come about this a different way?  All the examples I've seen with really aren't straightforward to me.  I know there is a log of information out there but nothing is really speaking to me.  I'm guessing the way I determine the titles[a] needs to be with a different method.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to show the window by specifying its name - if that worked, you wouldn't have needed to enumerate the windows!  What you need to pass as the first parameter to `ShowWindow()` is what you receved as the first parameter in your enumeration function.

Comment: jasonharper....the intention was to run a loop to check the list of open windows and if the expected window is not open, keep checking until the window opens, hence my getting the list.  If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.  

When I print out the array for 'titles', I know the name that I'm looking for is available and it's exactly the same name as in the list.  Unfortunately, putting that array location (title[a]) or the exact name 'My To Do List.xlsm - Excel' still doesn't equate to success.

Comment: `ShowWindow()` *doesn't want the title* - it wants the hWnd parameter that corresponds to it.  There can be any number of windows with the same title, after all.

Comment: The issue here must be that I'm not using a handler (hWnd) properly since that's what win32gui.ShowWindow is looking for.  Asking the routine to print the hwnd for each window results in the same output.  Is there something that can be used to activate a window based on a name provided vs a handler?

Comment: I found a fix...knowing the window name using the specified code above, I can then pass that name into the following function to activate the desired window...

_**import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate("My To Do List.xlsm - Excel") # specify the window                                                                                    
                                                                                # to activate**_

this activates the desired window. Thanks for your help @jasonharper